# Poisson equation on exterior of a ball

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $ B_1^c$ denote the compliment of the unit ball centered at the origin in $ R^N$ where $N \ge 3$.  I am interested in $ -\Delta u(x)=f(x)$ in $ B_1^c$ with $ u=0$ on $ \partial B_1^c$.   In particular let $ \sigma:=N-2+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ is small.    I am interested in solving the prior pde with an estimate of the form 
$$ \sup_{x \in B_1^c}|x|^{\sigma+1} | \nabla u(x)| \le C \sup_{B_1^c} |x|^{\sigma+2} |f(x)|$$ where $C$ is independent of $f,u$.       Note that all solutions $u$ cannot solve this since we can add $ c (|x|^{2-N}-1)$ to any solution.   So my question is: i seem to be able to prove the existence of a solution $u$ with the above desired property (using spherical harmonics and a blow up argument).   But this result seems a bit suspect to me.    Any comments on whether this is trivally false or possibly true would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: using an abstract argument i seem to be able to prove this for general exterior domains (here the domain doesn't include the origin).